# iOS / iPhone - AVAssetWriter : How to use endSessionAtSourceTime:

Tags: ios, iphone, video, avassetwriter, video-recording

I am using AVAssetWriter to create an MPEG4 file.

I start a video session with:

```
[assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];
```

Now the video file is written fine if I finish the session with this:

```
[assetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{


     }];
```

But if I call `[assetWriter endSessionAtSourceTime:endTime];` before `[assetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler` then it doesn't write the file.

This is how I call `endSessionAtSourceTime`:

```
endTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(secondsRecorded, 30);
    [assetWriter endSessionAtSourceTime:endTime];
```

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the behavior of endSessionAtSourceTime: doesn't do what you're expecting.

endSessionAtSourceTime: is almost the same thing as calling finishRecording() in that it stops the recording when called.  The difference is that after recording, endSessionAtSourceTime: will edit out (remove) any frames received after the specified sourceTime.

Instead, if your intended result is to record a 30second clip, you need to setup an NSTimer or something similar and then call endSessionAtSourceTime: or finishRecording() when the 30 seconds has elapsed